# Objective C unicode character comparisons

Tags: objective-c, unicode

How are unicode comparisons coded? I need to test exactly as below, checking for specific letters in a string. The code below chokes: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

```
for (charIndex = 0; charIndex < [myString length]; charIndex++)
{
   unichar testChar = [myString characterAtIndex:charIndex];

     if (testChar == "A")  
       // do something
     if (testChar == "B")
      // do something
     if (testChar == "C")
      // do something
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For char literals, use single quotes:

```
if (testChar == 'A') NSLog(@"It's an A");
```

Or represent the character using the code point number:

```
if (testChar == 0x1e01) NSLog(@"It's an A with a ring below");
```

The compiler sees double-quotes as a string, so builds "A" as equivalent to a `const char *` (which gives you there error message about the pointer).

Comment: This is not really correct.  Testing an individual `unichar` to see if it’s an ‘A’ may cause problems — for instance, if someone writes ‘Ä’, it may be encoded as `0041 0308`, in which case your code will detect the ‘A’ from the `0041`, or it might be encoded as `00C4` in which case your code won’t spot it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to do?  Doing direct character comparisons is unusual.  Typically -compare: or -isEqual: would be used to compare two strings.  Or NSScanner would be used to analyze the components of a string.

Comment: Good point. I wouldn't say that comparing characters is unusual, but looping through each character in a string does seem out of the ordinary. More "big picture" information would certainly help.