# My method always seems to return FALSE

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays

This method:

```
- (BOOL)checkForDigits {
    NSString *editableExpression = self.expression.text;
    for (int i = 0; i < editableExpression.length; i++){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
            char digitAtPosition = digits[c];
            if (charAtPosition == digitAtPosition){
                return TRUE;

            }
            else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

always seems to return FALSE and I can't figure out why. I would have used the isnan method but I tried that and it didn't work so I just made my own isnan (really the opposite of isnan). The digits array is just

```
char digits[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out. Place a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and step through it till you find out. Another possibility is that you are calling it on a nil pointer which will always "return" NO (not FALSE, although they are the same).

Comment: This method will only consider the first character of the `editableExpression` string. It will just tell you if this first character is between 1 and 9. Additionally, you are comparing integers with characters.

Comment: U want to check pure numbers and pure character or alphanumeric? In which case it should give true?

Comment: And btw. `'0'` is missing in your digits array. - And `isdigit()` checks for digits, not `isnan()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
- (BOOL)checkForDigits {
    char digits[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    BOOL result;
    NSString *editableExpression = @"dsjkdjk12lkv";
    for (int i = 0; i < editableExpression.length; i++){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
            char digitAtPosition = digits[c];
            if (charAtPosition == digitAtPosition){
                NSLog(@"true");
                return TRUE;

            }
            else {
                result = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Actually it was returning false in first loop only. So loop was running for one cycle only.

Answer (score 0):

Because

`charAtPosition` contain letter not digit such like `'1', '2',......`

[characterAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a) Returns the character at a given array position.

Comment: That's why I made the digits array a character array. Because I know charAtPosition *is* a character

Comment: instead of if, else you could just put:
return (charAtPosition == digitAtPosition);

Comment: @CW0007007- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997776/objective-c-unicode-character-comparisons/997799#997799

Comment: ... and now it gets worse and worse. iPatel: Your answer does not make sense *unless* you want to point out that `characterAtIndex` returns a 16-bit unichar which is truncated to a char. But as long as the input string does not contains characters > 0xFF this does not matter. - CW0007007: Of course `chars` are compared with ==.

Comment: Yes I realised that after I posted it. Amended it. I thought the meant "chars".

Comment: @iPatel: With 500+ answers you don't count as beginner :-) And (sorry!) this answer does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @MartinR- please, why does not help you to OP ?? in my answer `characterAtIndex ` return character at Index so OP has array of char such like ['A', 'D', 'R',.... etc] *(got frorm string)* and OP compared it with digit char array such like ['1', '2', '3'...etc]; so each time he/she got FALSE

Answer (score 0):

May be the better way will be use the NSScanner?

```
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
        NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&obj1String];
        obj1Num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[obj1String integerValue]];

        if(obj1String) {

        } else {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `editableExpression` not starting from digit.

```
NSString *editableExpression =@"A1" // return false

NSString *editableExpression =@"1A" // return True  

//This will return TRUE if string contain digit
- (BOOL)checkForDigits {
    NSString *editableExpression = @"1a1";
    for (int i = 0; i < editableExpression.length; i++){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
            char digitAtPosition = digits[c];
            if (charAtPosition == digitAtPosition){
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSRange match = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
if (match.location == NSNotFound) return NO;
else return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
BOOL containsDigits(NSString *s) {
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];
    NSRange range = [s rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cs];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify it by below way

```
- (BOOL)checkForDigits {
    NSString *editableExpression = self.expression.text;
    BOOL isDigit = FALSE;
    for (int i = 0; i < editableExpression.length; i++){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
            char digitAtPosition = digits[c];
            if (charAtPosition == digitAtPosition){
                 return TRUE;

            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```